# Trigonometric equation and how to solve them in general

Tags: trigonometry

I have to prove the equality $\frac{\sin4x}{1+\cos4x}.\frac{\cos2x}{1+\cos2x}.\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}=\tan\frac{x}{2}$

I looked at the fractions individually and got $({\sin4x}+{\tan4x}).({\cos2x+1}).(\cos x+1)=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ which I can't simplify further.

I looking for a solution to this problem and if someone can refer me to a document where it is explained how to go about solving different kinds of trigonometric equations.

Comment: Perhaps $1+\cos2x=2\cos^2 x$ can be useful for some denominators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prove the equality
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\,4x}{1+\cos\,4x}\cdot\frac{\cos\,2x}{1+\cos\,2x}\cdot\frac{\cos\,x}{1+\cos\,x}
&=\tan\tfrac{x}2
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Using just one known identity,
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\,x}{1+\cos\,x}&=\tan\tfrac{x}2
\end{align}
together with the definition $\tan\,x=\frac{\sin\,x}{\cos\, x}$,
LHS of \eqref{1} can be transformed as

\begin{align}
&=
\tan\tfrac{4x}{2}\cdot\frac{\cos\,2x}{1+\cos\,2x}\cdot\frac{\cos\,x}{1+\cos\,x}
\\
&=
\frac{\sin\,2x}{\cos\,2x}\cdot\frac{\cos\,2x}{1+\cos\,2x}\cdot\frac{\cos\,x}{1+\cos\,x}
\\
&=
\frac{\sin\,2x}{1+\cos\,2x}\cdot\frac{\cos\,x}{1+\cos\,x}
\\
&=
\tan\frac{2x}{2}\cdot\frac{\cos\,x}{1+\cos\,x}
\\
&=
\frac{\sin\,x}{\cos\,x}\cdot\frac{\cos\,x}{1+\cos\,x}
\\
&=
\frac{\sin\,x}{1+\cos\,x}
=\dots
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Notation: $\sin(nx)=s_n$ and similar for cos, and tan. Also let $t=\tan(x/2)=t_{1/2}$.
Then $$s_1=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, c_1=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\tag1$$
Then each factor in your fractions can be reduced to being a function of just $c_1,s_1$, e.g:
$$s_4=2s_2c_2=4s_1c_1(2c_1^2-1)$$
$$1+c_4=2c_2^2=2(1-s_2^2)=2(1-4s_1^2c_1^2)$$
Using the above equations $(1)$ should get you to the answer.

---

Motivation behind [$(1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).